# Selenium WebDriver: why it takes so long to select one country from 200 countries

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

Selenium WebDriver: why it takes so long to select one country from 200 countries? It takes about 4 seconds in a modern laptop (8G memory).

```
Select select = new Select(selectWebElement);
select.selectByValue("US");
```

About 200 country options.

Comment: What do you mean when you say it takes so long ? Please be more bit specific. Are you using `thread.sleep()` anywhere ?

Comment: Does it take same time for drop down load content manually ?

Comment: Do you use a custom "Select" class, or the default Selenium one? If it's the default class, then you could try to write your own selection function based on a WebElement instead. For example, I use:

select.FindElement(By.XPath($"//*[normalize-space()='{option}']")).Click();

Of course, "option" refers to the text (not value) of the element to click here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, If you are using only this piece of code :

```
Select select = new Select(selectWebElement);
select.selectByValue("US");
```

this should not take much time. As soon as the web element is available, selenium will pick it up. I suspect you must have `Thread.sleep(sometime)` before this code which is holding the execution for some time.